# Как развёртываются python приложения, созданные в виртуальных окружениях?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pip

Некоторое время назад начал заниматься разработкой приложения. По многочисленным советам разработка ведётся в виртуальном окружении, что заставило меня задуматься над вопросом - как готовое приложение будет разворачиваться на целевых машинах? Нужно осуществлять упаковку приложения + зависимых пакетов, или передавать сам пакет + requirements.txt? Venv не принято использовать в продакшене? В чём вообще тогда преимущество venv? Почему просто не устанавливать зависимости в систему на время разработки?

Comment: Как развёртывать приложения—это слишком обширная тема (и часть, относящаяся к Питону, является относительно небольшой, но также необъятной в общем случае—Питон во многих контекстах может быть использован). В разных случаях можно использовать: один исполняемый файл (eg, упакованный в PyInstaller), `pip install` (для Питон-программистов), `git push`, `curl https://.../install.sh | sh` (для любителей приключений), системные пакеты (eg, fpm, ppa на Ubuntu), docker-контейнеры, Fabric, Salt, Ansible итд итп. Конкретизируйте ваш вопрос: что за приложение, кто пользователь, какие конкретно требования.

Comment: Виртуальное окружение позволяет изолировать зависимости. Ситуация: одному проекту требуется первая версия библиотеки A, а другому - вторая версия той же библиотеки, что вы будете делать? Каждый раз её обновлять / даунгрейдить? Очевидно, что это не удобно. С виртуальным окружениями все просто - создаем по одному на проект и голова не болит. Оно также позволяет не захламлять глобальное окружение.

Comment: @jfs я же не спрашивал в целом о развёртывании приложений, а о развёртывании именно python-приложений. Я создал приложение в виртуальном окружении, что дальше? Неужели паковать окружение это pythonic-way? А обременять пользователей возней с виртуальными окружениями?

Comment: @PavelKarateev Допустим в PyPi находятся программки X и Y, с разным набором зависимостей, и я хочу использовать обе, я должен быть предусмотрительным и ставить venv для каждой из них? Ведь у них могут конфликтовать зависимости? Как __следует__ решать такие проблемы с python?

Comment: @jumpjet67 я вам и рассказываю про питон-приложения—только небольшая часть развёртывания уникальна для Питона. Если не уточните задачу, то можно несколько  книг написать на эту тему.

Comment: @jfs более-менее конкретной задачи нет. Сейчас я разрабатываю flask-приложение в виртуальном окружении. Соответственно есть зависимости от набора py-библиотек. Их стоит распространять вместе с приложением, пакуя в пакет? Такой вариант сильно захламляет систему. pip или deb могут поломать зависимости, так как две разные программы имею свои конфликтующие зависимости.

Comment: @jumpjet67 отредактируйте ваш вопрос, чтобы он содержал *одну* проблему, которая у вас действительно есть (гипотетических проблем может быть слишком много). Опишите кто пользователь, куда ставить собираетесь итд. Ответ, подходящий для развёртывания flask-сервиса на собственной домашней Raspberry Pi, отличается от ответа, который описывает как упаковывать один из тысяч микро-сервисов в какой-нибудь организации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во-первых, venv довольно часто используют и в продакшне, в том числе даже на недорогих хостингах, а на выделенном сервере его использовать тем более никто не помешает.

А как разворачивать приложения - это обширная тема. Кто-то использует docker-контейнеры или что-то подобное. В простейшем случае достаточно сам пакет + requirements.txt, ведь там можно указать нужные вам версии библиотек.

venv хорош тем, что можно делать свое окружение для каждого проекта. Иначе при переключении с проекта на проект требовалось бы переустанавливать библиотеки нужных версий.